# iPad tries to connect to Apple TV but then gives up

Tags: ipad, appletv

I am trying to set up my Apple TV and running into some difficulties.

I can see the mirroring option on the iPad, and when I select it I can see my Apple TV.  When I select these options it nothing happens. It looks like it's thinking about it for a second, then it just pops back to "iPad" — there is no error message.

I've updated the Apple TV.
Checked the network type (802.11n).
I know the TV is on the network as I can get at YouTube.

Any suggestions?